# Having difficulties with data set object

Tags: c#, object, dataset

I have created a data table using disconnected class, also created the data set,xml file, now I want to load that table in a grid. I wrote all my code under program.cs, but when I tried to access the data set object from the form load method, the data set object is not recognized. The code is here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace DisconnectedClassDemo
{
    public class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]


        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());



            DataTable studentInfo = new DataTable("studentinfo");

            DataColumn StudentID = new DataColumn("studentID");
            StudentID.DataType = typeof(int);
            StudentID.Caption="StudentID";
            StudentID.AutoIncrement = true;
            StudentID.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
            StudentID.AutoIncrementStep = 1;


            DataColumn Name = new DataColumn("StudentName", typeof(string));
            Name.MaxLength = 50;
            Name.AllowDBNull = false;
            Name.Caption = "StudentName";

            DataColumn Roll = new DataColumn("StudentRoll", typeof(int));
            Roll.Caption = "StudnetRoll";

            studentInfo.Columns.Add(StudentID);
            studentInfo.Columns.Add(Name);
            studentInfo.Columns.Add(Roll);

            studentInfo.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { StudentID };

            //DataRow rowobj = studentInfo.NewRow();
            //rowobj["studentName"] = "Badhon";
            //rowobj["studentRoll"] = "004";

            //studentInfo.Rows.Add(rowobj);


            DataSet ds = new DataSet("dataset");
            ds.Tables.Add(studentInfo);

            ds.WriteXmlSchema("D:\\Student.xsd");
            ds.WriteXml("D:\\student.xml");



            ds.ReadXmlSchema("d:\\student.xsd");
            ds.ReadXml("D:\\student.xml");







        }
    }



}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace DisconnectedClassDemo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //dataGridView1.DataSource= 
            //dataGridView1.DataMember=

        }




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you writing the data set to the file system? Aren't you trying to create an in memory dataset and the access that dataset? Try declaring the dataset on the form itself.

Try this:

```
            DataTable studentInfo = new DataTable("studentinfo");

        DataColumn StudentID = new DataColumn("studentID");
        StudentID.DataType = typeof(int);
        StudentID.Caption = "StudentID";
        StudentID.AutoIncrement = true;
        StudentID.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
        StudentID.AutoIncrementStep = 1;


        DataColumn Name = new DataColumn("StudentName", typeof(string));
        Name.MaxLength = 50;
        Name.AllowDBNull = false;
        Name.Caption = "StudentName";

        DataColumn Roll = new DataColumn("StudentRoll", typeof(int));
        Roll.Caption = "StudnetRoll";

        studentInfo.Columns.Add(StudentID);
        studentInfo.Columns.Add(Name);
        studentInfo.Columns.Add(Roll);

        studentInfo.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { StudentID };

        DataSet ds = new DataSet("dataset");
        ds.Tables.Add(studentInfo);

        var rw = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();

        rw["StudentName"] = "Badhon";
        rw["StudentRoll"] = 004;

        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(rw);

        MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString());

        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Ok...I moved my code within the form load method. but still the table is not showing on the grid. I assigned the datasource of the grid as the data set object, still no result. Is there anything else I'm missing? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Thanks again...The problem is now solved. Tell me one thing, is it possible to take the input from a text box to populate the data table while working with in memory data base? I tried, showing no error, but also not showing the data in that column?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the form before the dataset

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Move this line down below the creation of the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Like Preet Sangha says, you're creating and running the form before the dataset.

Also, the dataset is a local variable inside your Main method so the form class has no knowledge of it. Try creating the dataset inside the form or passing it as a parameter to the constructor:

```
public class Form1(Dataset ds) : Form 
...


...

Application.Run(new Form1(ds));
```